# Make WrapPanel add items from bottom to top

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can I make `WrapPanel` add items from bottom to top?

Do I need to write a custom control for that or any easy way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code behind you can just use the Insert() method on the Children property.

```
WrapPanel myPanel = new WrapPanel();
myPanel.Children.Insert(0, new Button());
```

If not in code behind, you'll have to create a new control.